# IntelliJ Idea - Move each inner static classes to own file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a java file with loads of static inner classes, is there a way of moving all of them to their own files at once with IntelliJ Idea? I tried highlighting every class and using F6 but I was only able to move the outer class, in which they are all contained.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in IntelliJ IDEA out of the box. It's possible to implement this in a plugin, but I'm not aware of any existing plugin that provides this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is such a feature that works for `.java` files [image: Select Refectoring]

Comment: Yes but this will only move one file at a time, not all of them.